# How to solve ERROR 1060: Duplicate column name using Views -> Create View

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I am trying to create a view from joining some tables (in MySQL) from Sakila database (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/), namely I want to join payment, staff and customer and display the customer's name, the staff's name, the payment id and amount. 
I right clicked on Views and then Create Table. 
I think this error exists because of the fact that in the staff table and in the customer table there are both columns named first_name and last_name. How could I solve this problem?

My code:

```
CREATE VIEW `payment` AS
SELECT payment.payment_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, 
staff.first_name, staff.last_name, payment.amount
FROM payment INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_ID = customer.customer_ID
INNER JOIN staff ON payment.staff_ID = staff.staff_ID
```

The error message:
ERROR 1060: Duplicate column name 'first_name'

If I try it with aliases, as some of the answerers suggested, I get the error ERROR 1347: 'sakila.payment' is not VIEW.

The exact same code works like a charm in SQL File, when I run it, it creates the table I need. What is the difference between these two methods? Which one should I use? And why didn't it work with the Views -> Create View option?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you won't get the error as posted from the join you show here as you have defined which first_name column you want by defining it from the customer table. Perhaps in your actual join you did not specify the table.

Comment: try SELECT payment.payment_id, customer.first_name as customer_firstname, customer.last_name as customer_last_name ... and so on... in other words, add alias to the same column names...

Comment: @Niagaradad, I did specify the table in the actual join

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use aliases to assign names:

```
CREATE VIEW v_payment AS
    SELECT p.payment_id, c.first_name as customer_first_name, c.last_name as customer_last_name,
           s.first_name as staff_first_name, s.last_name as staff_last_name,
           p.amount
    FROM payment p INNER JOIN
         customer c
         ON p.customer_ID = c.customer_ID INNER JOIN
         staff s
         ON p.staff_ID = s.staff_ID;
```

`first_name` and `last_name` appear twice in your `select` list.  The above clarifies whether the name is for a customer or staff.

Comment: Now I get an error saying ERROR 1347: 'sakila.payment' is not VIEW. I have already tried using AS in the SELECT statement, but it didn't work, I got this exact error back then too.

Comment: @LillaNagy . . . I missed that you are trying to give the view the same name as the table.  Views have to have different names.  I often prepend them with `v_` for this purpose.

Comment: It's okay, I forgot to mention this, I only edited it a few minutes ago. Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 5):

The restriction is that the column names must be unique.

The SELECT query is probably valid, but it does return columns that have the same name. Two columns with the name `first_name`, and two columns named `last_name`.

The error crops up when we use the query as a view (either an inline view, or a stored view.)

The workaround is to rename the columns by providing a column *alias*, so that no two columns in the resultset have the same name. For example:

```
SELECT payment.payment_id
     , customer.first_name   AS customer_first_name
     , customer.last_name    AS customer_last_name
     , staff.first_name      AS staff_first_name
     , staff.last_name       AS staff_last_name
     , payment.amount
  FROM payment 
  JOIN customer
    ON ...
  JOIN staff
    ON ...
```